# filter out the row data while searching from input

Tags: reactjs

I try to filter out the row data, which is displaying in UI
am unable to filter out row data when either name or lname matches the searched criteria ie search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just refactor couple things I removed it:

```
const filterData = () => {
    if (search === "") {
      return items;
    }
  };
```

then I update items as function where if search is defined as props do you filter

```
import React from "react";
export const CustTable = ({ columns, data, setData, search, setSearch }) => {
  const [editable, setEditable] = React.useState("");
  const cellEditable = (label) => {
    data.map((l) => {
      if (l.name === label.name) {
        setEditable(label.name);
      }
    });
  };
  const changeLastName = (name, e, index) => {
    e.persist();
    setData((prevData) => {
      return [
        ...prevData.slice(0, index),
        { name, lname: e.target.value },
        ...prevData.slice(index + 1)
      ];
    });
  };
  const items = () => {
    let resultItems = data;
    if (search) {
      resultItems = data.filter((item) =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
      );
    }

    return resultItems.map((label, index) => {
      return (
        <tr style={{ display: "flex" }} key={index}>
          <span style={{ width: "35%" }}>{label.name} </span>
          {editable === label.name ? (
            <input
              type="text"
              value={label.lname}
              onChange={(e) => changeLastName(label.name, e, index)}
            />
          ) : (
            <span onClick={() => cellEditable(label)}>{label.lname} </span>
          )}
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  const searchData = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <input
          type="search"
          placeholder="search"
          onChange={(e) => searchData(e)}
        />
      </div>
      {items()}
    </>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/customtablereact-forked-f01c6